# Romanize Korean hangul script in accordance with the official 'Revised Romanization of Korean'

Tags: r, text, cjk

I wish to romanize Korean place names from *hangul* script. Function `stringi::stri_trans_general` supports *hangul* romanization, but apparently not in accordance with the widely applied and official *[Revised Romanization of Korean](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Revised_Romanization_of_Korean)* scheme.

The code below reveals some of the potential conversion issues:

```
library(stringi)
Sys.setlocale(category="LC_ALL", locale="Korean")

#Read hangul "서울특별시 종로구 사직동" pasted in win10 notepad file because directly pasting in console doesn't work
x <- readLines("hangul.txt", encoding="UTF-8")

#Try the two different tranform identifiers I have found in stri_trans_list for hangul-to-latin
stri_trans_general(x, "Hangul-Latin")
[1] "seoulteugbyeolsi jonglogu sajigdong"
stri_trans_general(x, "Hang-Lat")
[1] "seoulteugbyeolsi jonglogu sajigdong"
```

According to the *Revised Romanization of Korean*, the output should be "seoulteu**K**byeolsi jong**N**ogu saji**K**dong" instead of "seoulteu**G**byeolsi jong**L**ogu saji**G**dong" (my uppercase for emphasis). How can the desired romanisation be achieved in *R*, with `stringi` or otherwise?

Answer (score 2):

The manual says that `stri_trans_general` uses the ICU library to do transliteration, and the ICU manual says that it uses "Korean Ministry of Culture & Tourism Transliteration with the clause 8 variant for reversibility".  I don't know how different that is from the scheme you want, but it is possible in the very recent development version 1.6.2.9004 of `stringi` to modify the transliteration.

To get this version, use

```
remotes::install_github("gagolews/stringi")
```

This will require compiling, so you may need to install some extra tools to use it.  It takes a while to run...

Once you have it, you can do things like this (from the revised help page for `stri_trans_general`):

```
x <- "\uC11C\uC6B8\uD2B9\uBCC4\uC2DC\u0020\uC885\uB85C\uAD6C\u0020\uC0AC\uC9C1\uB3D9"
stringi::stri_trans_general(x, "Hangul-Latin")
## [1] "seoulteugbyeolsi jonglogu sajigdong"
# Deviate from the ICU rules of Romanisation of Korean,
# see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%84%B1
id <- "
    :: NFD;
    \u11A8 > k;
    \u11AE > t;
    \u11B8 > p;
    \u1105 > r;
    :: Hangul-Latin;
"
stringi::stri_trans_general(x, id, rules=TRUE)
## [1] "seoulteukbyeolsi jongrogu sajikdong"
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Can rules be made about *combinations* of characters? Korean phonology has *[sandhis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sandhi)* which affect romanisation. For example, "ㄹ" (\u1105) romanises as "n" after "ㅇ" (\u3147) but as "r" or " l" in other cases.

Comment: Yes, quite complex rules are possible.  See the ICU User Guide reference linked from the help page.